# Combine RewriteRules in .htaccess so that a specific query parameter is ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to write some RewriteRules so that when a request contains a specific query parameter, let's call it `foo`, it is ignored (removed) completely. The reason for this is that I need to use `foo` internally in another RewriteRule so that I can pass information to my front controller. If `foo` would already exist, the application wouldn't work as intended. I tried multiple solutions, for example [this](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/website-tips/htaccess-how-to-remove-a-single-query-parameter-from-a-url/) one, but that doesn't do what I'd like to achieve. So far, I tried the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Remove possible existing query parameter called 'foo'
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?foo=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]

# Lead every page/API request to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(svg|jpg|png|webp|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|woff2)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?foo=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Basically, every request which doesn't end with one of the listed file extensions should be passed to my front controller. Without the lines 5 and 6 everything works fine as long as no `foo` query parameter exists in the original request.

Is there a way to just remove the `foo` parameter without affecting the other RewriteRule (or simply to override it in the second part)? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Just to clarify a few things: In my application, the front controller is a PHP script that takes the rewritten GET parameter `foo`, which contains the originally requested URL. However, if the user adds `foo` to the request, I have to make sure this is not the `foo` parameter that gets passed to the front controller as the app wouldn't work properly then.

For example: If the client requests `https://example.com/something?foo=123&bar=456`, the request should be redirected to `https://example.com/something?bar=456` (or alternatively not redirected at all) and the query parameter `foo` in line 9, which is intended for my front controller only, should be `https://example.com/something` with `bar` not being changed. Unfortunately, the above code wont't do this. Instead, I'm redirected to `https://example.com/index.php?bar=456`. I guess the solution is actually pretty simple, but I'm not able to find out how to do it.

Comment: Its really great that you have shared your efforts and htaccess file in your qustion, keep it up. Could you please also share from which URL(samples only)  to which URL(backend) you want to serve wth for more clarity of your question, thank you.

Comment: It's really just about how to "reserve" a specific query parameter for internal use. I will clarify that in my question shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following. please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Considering here you need everything after `&` in query string to be passed in rewritten URL here. Added 2 existing rules from OP's htaccess file and changed place for https rule moved it to very first place.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##From OP's comments adding these here, http --> https should come first.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove possible existing query parameter called 'foo'
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?foo=[^&]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [NE,L]

# Lead every page/API request to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(svg|jpg|png|webp|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|woff2)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?foo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: My browser says `Error: Request could not be executed`. It was originally in German, I hope this translation is meaningful.

Comment: @Boostinger, I am sorry my mobile did an auto correct could you please check rules now and let me know then.

Comment: Now the error is gone, but it doesn't prevent me from using the query parameter. Just to be sure, should I replace my lines 5 and 6? Thanks for your effort btw.

Comment: @Boostinger, cool. So I see you already a rule for foo so are you replacing these rules with them kindly confirm once

Comment: Both "blocks"? I guess it wouldn't pass `foo` to my controller if I replaced both. Am I right? So what I did was replacing just the first condition + rule (lines 5 & 6).

Comment: @Boostinger, Could you please try my edited rules once and kindly do let me know how it goes and yes try to put these rules on your 5th and 6th lines place.

Comment: The controller still gets the `foo` passed in my request, not the rewritten version according to my lines 9 and 10.

Comment: @Boostinger, When I check url `http://localhost/something?foo=123&bar=456` it gets rewritten to `http://localhost/something?bar=456` in my local and I kept your 2nd rule also in my htaccess file. Could you please do let me know if you have any other rules in your htaccess file too apart from these 2.

Comment: Yes, I remove trailing slashes and force https apart from the rules mentioned.
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]` (sorry for the bad formatting)

Comment: @Boostinger, Ok, keep your making it to `https` rule as very first rules, place them above these 2 rules. Also is your 2nd rule needed to be checked like url has `http://localhost:80/page/API?b;blablabla` in it? If yes then we can put that condition too in your current API rule, let me know on same once.

Comment: Yes, the latest update seems to work! The only occasion where it still behaves differently is the root. If I request `https://example.com/?foo=123&bar=456` the content of `$_GET` in my PHP script is `Array ( [foo] => foo=123 [bar] => 456 )`.

Comment: @Boostinger, great that it worked for most of the URLs :) honestly I am not sure about php part, so you mean to say your `$_GET` variable should only have `[bar]` value here? If yes then by any chance our 3rd rule is affecting it? Could you please post working urls example too(along with my previous question in this comment itself), kindly do let me know.

Comment: I just put the PHP output in for you to be able to see what values the parameters contain now. It should look like this in order to work as intended: `Array ( [foo] =>  [bar] => 456 )` - so `foo` is expected to be an empty string because it is the root. Note that `foo` would get a value of `something` for `/something?foo=123&bar=456`, which already works great. As an answer to your previous question: I think URLs as in your example are not necessary to be handled at the moment.

Comment: @Boostinger, Happy that my answer helped you, also If new condition is not working OR you are OK without new condition in 3rd rule then please do let me know will remove it from solution then.

Comment: I will check it out. I think it already worked before that latest change as it seems. My apologies, I might have typed something wrong during the check. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Boostinger, oh ok no issues then, I have made it to previous one now(no extra redirect status check condition in 3rd rule), cheers and happy learning, keep sharing on this great forum.

Comment: @Boostinger, For rule line `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?foo=[^&]+&?(.*)$` expression `.*` is really greedy if you have only 2 times `&` in your line then we could make it better, if you confirm it then I will add it later morning, cheers.

Comment: no problem. If there is a better/cleaner solution, just add it whenever you got time. It works now for me, so I'm happy. But I'm still interested in how to do this properly of course and I will check it out if there's something new.